# Chrome Webkit Elements only show up in Developer Mode

Tags: windows, google-chrome, webkit

Everything is great on all browsers on OS X, I come to test on windows, and it seems my webkit elements, ie gradient backgrounds and radius borders do not show up - in chrome, firefox or ie. (so it isn't a problem with chrome exclusively but perhaps Windows 7?) I should not i'm on chrome 27 and ie 10. On another windows pc with an earlier chrome and ie 8 it looks as it should.

So,  I go into chrome developer mode to take a look, and when I rollover the 'element', I can actually see the webkit items as they should be under the highlighted colour. Does that make sense?

Anyone experienced this before and know what it means?

For example, the following will be invisible in all windows browsers, but when I hover over it in chrome it shows up:

```
.example .example1 li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-left: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maby you need to run your code through a Prefixer, http://prefixr.com/